# How to filter a map using Lambda?

Tags: lambda, haxe

I have a map variable:

```
var bitmapDepths:Map<BitmapData, Int>;
```

What I need is to remove all keys with value of 0, I tried this:

```
bitmapDepths= Lambda.filter(Lambda.list(bitmapDepths.keys), function(v) { return (v > 0); });
```

So, I used Lambda.list to iterate on bitmapDepths.keys inside Lambda, but I get this error:

```
Void -> Iterator<flash.display.BitmapData> should be Iterable<Unknown<0>>
```

I tried Lambda.array to iterate on bitmapDepths.keys, I got the same error, so who can handle this? to remove keys based on values using Lambda?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use Lambda. It's a class that has been added in Haxe 1. In Haxe 3, for loops/comprehensions are almost always the better choice.

To remove the keys in place:

```
for (k in bitmapDepths.keys()) if (k == 0) bitmapDepths.remove(k);
```

To construct a new map:

```
bitmapDepths = [for (k in bitmapDepths.keys()) if (k != 0) k => bitmapDepths.get(k)];
```

Not only is it shorter, it also has better runtime performance.

Comment: i made a quick test lambda.fold vs Reflect.compare ( which doesn't work) vs loop
http://try.haxe.org/#daAAE