# Usage of Lambda.filter() in haxe typed iterables or equivalent functional construct

Tags: lambda, list-comprehension, haxe, lazy-sequences

How can I make the haxe Lambda.filter work with a typed iterable? The next code refuses to compile because of a bad type:

`Iterator<Int> should be Iterable<Unknown<0>>
{ next : Void -> Int, hasNext : Void -> Bool } should be Iterable<Unknown<0>>`

Code example:

```
import Lambda;
import openfl.events.KeyboardEvent;

class KeyBoard {
    private var keys:Map<Int,Bool>;
    public function new() keys = new Map();
    public function key_handler(key:KeyboardEvent) {
        if (key.type == KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN) keys.set(key.keyCode, true);
        if (key.type == KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP) keys.remove(key.keyCode);
    }
    public function keys_down() {
        return Lambda.filter(keys.keys(), function(k:Int) { return keys.exists(k);});
        // The comprehension working alternative:
        //return [for (k in keys.keys()) if (keys.exists(k)) k];

    }
}
```

I am aware it [has been asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20299483/how-to-filter-a-map-using-lambda) but the answer gave an alternative implementation which I can find by myself rather than an accurate answer about its usage. I find the Lambda constructs a basic component for functional programming, especially at time to create lazy compositions using map/reduce, and I understand that the list comprehensions don't replace them.

If the Lambda constructs really have to disappear, and list comprehensions are really the way to go in Haxe 3, why the Lambda module is still there and how can they be used to achieve laziness or unlimited levels of better composition?

Edit: A way to make it work is to expand the iterable into an array which for sure is not an actual solution (looping twice the same sequence!):

```
Lambda.filter([for (i in keys.keys()) i], function(k:Int) { return keys.exists(k); });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try to code a lazy version of the Lambda class.

(I have done that in the [past](https://github.com/jonasmalacofilho/vehjo.hx/blob/master/lib/vehjo/LazyLambda.hx), but I don't use it any more since it worked with expressions and reserved identifiers instead of functions/short lambdas, and I now think that was stupid).

Alternatively, you can use something like this:

```
using Test.IteratorTools;

class IteratorTools {
    public static function toIterable<T>(f:Void->Iterator<T>):Iterable<T>
    {
        return {
            iterator : f
        };
    }
}

class Test {
    static function main() {
        var map = ["a" => "abc", "b" => "bcd", "c" => "cde"];
        var fkeys = Lambda.filter(map.keys.toIterable(), function(k) return k != "c");
        trace(fkeys);
    }
}
```

Note that for this to work you need a development version of haxe, at least with commit [HaxeFoundation/haxe@f6cd97b](https://github.com/HaxeFoundation/haxe/commit/f6cd97bed19459a100c57887740ce3a09cec2c8c).  Otherwise, you will get "Cannot create closure on abstract member inline method" errors.

Comment: Hi, I wonder what the downside of the lazylambda was, it looks quite nice to me. Why would functions be better?

Comment: Maybe it wasn't 'stupid', it's just that not I think something in the direction of short lambdas (even if later they were always inlined) would be better. There were some performance gains, but the behaviour I chose didn't really solve the verbosity issue. Sure, the lambda calls got shorter, but by using fixed identifiers (for example `$x`) the readability of user code also decreased, and the use next to string interpolations became really confusing.  Take this: currently I would have to write `vertices.map($x.x + ',' + $x.y )`, instead of the more readable `vertices.map(v => '${v.x},{v,y}')`.

Comment: @MarkKnol, I would love to hear more thoughts on the subject. Please feel free to _also_ open an issue or reach me directly by email.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the difference between Iterable and Iterator in Haxe, and Lambda doesn't work by default with Iterator (it is lacking the support at it is reported in the official community [bug tracking](https://github.com/HaxeFoundation/haxe/issues/1914) utility form the community).

The topic could be considered duplicated:
[Lambda iteration over an Iterator (not an Iterable)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25648390/lambda-iteration-over-an-iterator-not-an-iterable)

In the current status the Lambda utilities are just obsolete and not enough usable.

Comment: The current Lambda utilities are still sometimes useful, but yes, we're lacking lazy versions of them that work primarily on Iterators, instead of Iterables.  Building something that works like that is easy enough (perhaps even with some syntactic sugar like short lambdas) and could eventually even get into the standard library someday.

Comment: Yes, you are right saying it is still useful, however I find it not valid for all possible outputs from the current std library data structure methods which makes it not a generic reliable tool for all cases... As you say a new library should take its place somewhen in the future bringing the latest and greatest lessons learned from other languages.